# Telnet SSH Connection with Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, ssh, telnet, pxssh

I try to connect to a ssh server (port 22) with python in windows environment, but it is unsuccessful with pexpect, pxssh for windows. Is there another solution?

Comment: See this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295501/ssh-and-telnet-to-localhost-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295501/ssh-and-telnet-to-localhost-using-python)

Comment: What is a "Telnet SSH Connection"? What is "a ssh telnet server"? Telnet and SSH are different protocols.

Comment: SSH Protocol Port 22

Comment: So just regular SSH? What does "it is unsuccessful" mean? Do you get a timeout? A refused connection? Some other error message? Can you successfully SSH between the two machines outside of Python? Please read [ask].